# Android ShoppingList Master Detail Flow

Tags: java, android, master-detail

I am trying to make a ShoppingList using a master-detail flow.
but when I try to save a post I get a NullPointerException when trying to read from the EditText's I have in the DetailFragment.
this is my DetailFragment Class

```
public class ItemDetailFragment extends Fragment{

int id = 0;
private EditText name, amount, comment;
private CheckBox done;
public static final String ARG_ITEM_ID = "item_id";
private ItemContent.Item mItem;

public ItemDetailFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (getArguments().containsKey(ARG_ITEM_ID)) {
        mItem = ItemContent.ITEM_MAP.get(getArguments().getString(ARG_ITEM_ID));
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_detail, container, false);

    if (mItem != null) {
        name = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editName);
        name.setText(mItem.getName());
        amount = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editAmount);
        amount.setText(mItem.getAmount());
        comment = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editComment);
        comment.setText(mItem.getComment());
        done = (CheckBox) rootView.findViewById(R.id.checkDone);
        done.setChecked(mItem.getDone());
    }

    return rootView;
}

public void save(){
    id++;
    String idSave = id + "";
    String nameSave = name.getText().toString();
    String amountSave = amount.getText().toString();
    String commentSave = comment.getText().toString();
    Boolean doneSave;
    if(done.isChecked())
        doneSave =true;
    else
        doneSave = false;

    mItem.setId(idSave);
    mItem.setName(nameSave);
    mItem.setAmount(amountSave);
    mItem.setComment(commentSave);
    mItem.setDone(doneSave);
    ItemContent ic = new ItemContent();
    ic.addItem(mItem);
}

}
```

and this is my DetailActivity Class

```
public class ItemDetailActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_detail);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putString(ItemDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, getIntent().getStringExtra(ItemDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID));
        ItemDetailFragment fragment = new ItemDetailFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(arguments);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.item_detail_container, fragment).commit();
    }
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_detail, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.save:
        ItemDetailFragment idf = new ItemDetailFragment();
        idf.save();
        break;
    case R.id.cancel:
        this.finish();
        break;
    case R.id.home:
        NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this,new Intent(this, ItemListActivity.class));
        break;  
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

This is where things go wrong. When I select an object in my list I can get the EditItem to display the strings from the selected list element but I cant get the text from the EditText to a string...

```
03-13 13:05:45.760: E/AndroidRuntime(451): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-13 13:05:45.760: E/AndroidRuntime(451): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-13 13:05:45.760: E/AndroidRuntime(451):  at com.example.list.ItemDetailFragment.save(ItemDetailFragment.java:53)
03-13 13:05:45.760: E/AndroidRuntime(451):  at com.example.list.ItemDetailActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(ItemDetailActivity.java:37)
```

Can someone see what I'm doing wrong or should I do it a completely other way?

Comment: The exception is at line `53` (ItemDetailFragment.java:53), which line is it in your code?

Comment: idf.save(); in Item detail Activity and in Item detail Fragment String nameSave = name.getText().toString();

Comment: Try to debug your code, `name` or `name.getText()` is null in your case. First find what is null and then if `name` is null then check why it is null and if `name.getText()` is null then before doing `toString()` first do a null check for `name.getText()`.

Comment: It is name that has the null value. i guess since it's not associated with the EditText in the view.

Comment: Then check your code in `onCreateView`. Why it is null.. And if the expected value is null then you need to add null check in ur code...